# DX11 fonts using GDI

Tags: c++, directx-11

Has anybody found a way to easily overlay text onto a DirectX 11 window (using C++)?

I would normally render to a bitmap and use it as a texture in my 3D scene, however this is for a development tool where I just need to print some basic info (fps, polygon count, etc.) in the top left corner, similar to Max or Maya's render window.

Is it possible to do something like print GDI text on top of the window on the paint message, etc? It seems like overkill to implement an entire font rendering system just for 3 lines of text. I have heard of 'surface sharing' using DX10 and Direct2D, but again this sounds like a hassle for what I am after.

Thanks

Comment: Are you already hooking the app to determine FPS, poly count, etc., or does this information come from elsewhere?

Comment: This is my own application, so I am calculating everything myself. I can print out on another window using GDI, I would just like to be able to overlay like Max and Maya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpriteFont in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) is a light-weight bitmap-based font renderer for Direct3D 11.

Note that with DirectX 11.1 (Windows 8.x and Windows 7 SP1 with KB[2670838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838) you can use Direct2D/DirectWrite on a DirectX 11.x device without dealing with the complexities of [DXGI surface sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554.aspx).